# Intent starting multiple activities

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-earth, geo

I'm trying to write an activity that will display a location using a geo:// URL when a button is pushed. My problem is that after selecting Google Maps, the Google Earth activity launches immediatly in the same task.

Code

```
public void onViewOnMapClicked(View view)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo://0,0"));

    if(i != null){
        try {
            this.startActivity(i);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Bizarrely, if I select Google Earth, there is no problem. The location is not handled properly however. Could that be the same issue?
I can't shake the feeling that I am doing something horribly wrong here.

I have tested this on Samsung Galaxy S3 running ICS and on my Nexus 7 running JB 4.2. API Level is 15.

Comment: Try the correct form of the `Uri`: `geo:0,0`. There is no `//` in the `geo:` syntax: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

Comment: Yup, that fixed it for me. As expected, this was a stupid mistake. Given that this is a URI, any idea why the '//' is not required?

Comment: Not all `Uri` values take slashes. `mailto:` doesn't, for example, and that's been around for ages. I *think* the slashes are tied to having a host (`http://`) versus not (`mailto:`), but that's just a guess.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the feedback.